# 1Password Integration with SE Mobile App

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, mobile-app

Making a feature request to add a third-party integration for password managers like 1Password within the app login screen so I don't have to leave the app to open another app to get my password.

Here's an example from Slack's iOS app:

[image: Slack's login screen]

Comment: ooooo. If this is possible on Android I want it there too, as I am a heretic and use 1Password on an array of non-Apple devices.